# Add "Use Default Option" In Custom Category Attribute In Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, category-attribute

I am creating a custom category attribute. When I am changing the store view language, then Use Default Option not appearing.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the category attribute, you need to add a global attribute as the scope store

```
$categorySetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
    'is_emotion',
    [
        ....
        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        ....
    ]
);
```

Comment: I mentioned same as you mentioned but not use its not working.

Comment: Can you send me your create attribute script?

Comment: How can I send?

Comment: This is the magento issue with the category attribute https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13440
I think it's not related to your create attribute script

Comment: Okay, thanks may be lettered on updated it can resolve.